# New Xcode 3.2.6 only for iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, version, compatibility

I am wondering if using Xcode 3.2.6 will create apps that will work with all iphones,
should I use an older version ? Sorry I am green at this

Answer (score 2):

You can use both Xcode 3.x and 4.x to develop applications for both Mac OS X and *all* of the iOS devices. You can simply select a target iOS version within your project, although you're still responsible for ensuring that you don't use iOS calls that aren't available in that version. (`instancesRespondToSelector:` is your friend, etc.)

However, I'd be tempted to use the latest version (4.0.1 as of the time of writing), which is available from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ (a developer account login will be required), if only because Xcode 4 has the Interface Builder built in, has Git support out of the box, etc.

Comment: Just to give a contrary view: there seem to be a huge number of teething problems with Xcode 4 (and 4.0.1) - I'd stick with 3.2.6 for a while until it's matured a bit.

Comment: @Paul True - if the OP already has Xcode 3.x and is used to it, then I'd agree. However, if they're coming to Xcode "fresh", then I'd be tempted to jump into Xcode 4 straight away.

Comment: @middaparka: good point - the user interface and many other features are quite different between 3.x and 4.x

Comment: @Paul Yup - the pain of some (hopefully) minor issues is *just about* offset by the cost of later having to re-learn bits of the IDE.

Comment: Right, I hear the latest version are intricate but my actual xCode version doesn't seem to let me access The Interface Builder through the "mainwindow.xib. @Middparka: that means I should look for the 4.0.1 version ?

Comment: Otherwise I'll stick to 3.2.6 and learn the hard way untill they improve the kit.

Comment: @Francis If you double click the XIB file within your project, it should fire up Interface Builder. If this isn't happening, it sounds like your install might be a bit under the weather. :-)

Comment: @middparka thx I'll look that up ! Reinstall now as a matter of fact

Comment: Gee it needs 1H30 to install, I'll be watching the tutorials from apple in the meantime.

Comment: @middparka I just reinstalled the kit and I still can't access Interface Builder

Comment: Now I'm officially pissed, I must uninstall and download an other version.. but wich

Comment: I figure something out; Interface builder does not fire up by itself when I double click the XIB file... I must open it on it's own